# Flutter: How to make a login in flutter

Tags: authentication, flutter

[![Here is the button that the users will click][1]][1]     How can I  make and display a login form this is what I'm trying to do.
after a user clicked on the first button. 
This is where I want to put the Login Form in the class SecondScreen.Also, I want to learn how to make a simple login form in Flutter

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topLeft, end: Alignment.bottomRight, colors: [Colors.amberAccent, Colors.red]),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // add Column
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Welcome2',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    // your text
                      fontSize: 50.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white)),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text('Button'),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                color: Colors.white,
                splashColor: Colors.blue,
                textColor: Color(0xfffe67e22),
              ), // your button beneath text
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 4):

For simple login form you you can do like this,

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_stack/color_utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_stack/common_styles.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_stack/raised_gradient_button.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _LoginScreenState();
  }
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.40,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: ColorUtils.appBarGradient),
              ),
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
                    child: Text(
                      "Login",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          fontSize: 19),
                    ),
                  )),
              Positioned(
                top: 150,
                left: 10,
                right: 10,
                child: LoginFormWidget(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginFormWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoginFormWidgetState();
  }
}

class _LoginFormWidgetState extends State<LoginFormWidget> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _userEmailController = TextEditingController(text: "jm1@example.com");
  var _userPasswordController = TextEditingController(text: "jay@123");
  var _emailFocusNode = FocusNode();
  var _passwordFocusNode = FocusNode();
  bool _isPasswordVisible = true;
  bool _autoValidate = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      autovalidate: _autoValidate,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            elevation: 8,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildLogo(),
                _buildIntroText(),
                _buildEmailField(context),
                _buildPasswordField(context),
                _buildForgotPasswordWidget(context),
                _buildSignUpButton(context),
                _buildLoginOptionText(),
                _buildSocialLoginRow(context),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          _buildSignUp(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSocialLoginRow(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          __buildFacebookButtonWidget(context),
          __buildTwitterButtonWidget(context)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget __buildTwitterButtonWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: RaisedButton(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(29, 161, 242, 1.0),
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/ic_twitter.png",
              width: 25,
              height: 25,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget __buildFacebookButtonWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: RaisedButton(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(42, 82, 151, 1.0),
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/ic_fb.png",
              width: 35,
              height: 35,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLoginOptionText() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Text(
        "Or sign up with social account",
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black54, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildIntroText() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 30),
          child: Text(
            "My Recipes",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black54,
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLogo() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      child: Image.asset(
        "assets/images/ic_launcher.png",
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
      ),
    );
  }

  String _userNameValidation(String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return "Please enter valid user name";
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Widget _buildEmailField(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 5),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _userEmailController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_passwordFocusNode);
        },
        validator: (value) => _emailValidation(value),
        decoration: CommonStyles.textFormFieldStyle("Email", ""),
      ),
    );
  }

  String _emailValidation(String value) {
    bool emailValid =
        RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+").hasMatch(value);
    if (!emailValid) {
      return "Enter valid email address";
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Widget _buildPasswordField(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 5),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _userPasswordController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_emailFocusNode);
        },
        validator: (value) => _userNameValidation(value),
        obscureText: _isPasswordVisible,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Password",
          hintText: "",
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          alignLabelWithHint: true,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                _isPasswordVisible ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _isPasswordVisible = !_isPasswordVisible;
                });
              }),
          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildForgotPasswordWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              'Forgot your password ?',
              style:
                  TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSignUpButton(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 15.0),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: RaisedGradientButton(
          child: Text(
            "Login",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            _signUpProcess(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _signUpProcess(BuildContext context) {
    var validate = _formKey.currentState.validate();

    if (validate) {
      //Do login stuff
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _autoValidate = true;
      });
    }
  }

  void _clearAllFields() {
    setState(() {
      _userEmailController = TextEditingController(text: "");
      _userPasswordController = TextEditingController(text: "");
    });
  }

  Widget _buildSignUp() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(
              text: "Don't have an Account ? ",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Register',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  fontSize: 14),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

color_utils.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColorUtils {
  static const Color primaryColor = Color(0xffEC9F05);
  static const Color accentColor = Color(0xffFF4E00);
  static const Color orangeGradientEnd = Color(0xfffc4a1a);
  static const Color orangeGradientStart = Color(0xfff7b733);
  static const Color themeGradientStart = Color(0xFF8E24AA);
  static const Color themeGradientEnd = Color(0xFFFB8C00);
  static const LinearGradient appBarGradient =
      LinearGradient(colors: [themeGradientStart, themeGradientEnd]);
}
```

common_styles.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CommonStyles {
  static textFormFieldStyle(String label, String hint) {
    return InputDecoration(
      labelText: label,
      hintText: hint,
      alignLabelWithHint:true,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 2
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

raised_gradient_button.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_stack/color_utils.dart';

class RaisedGradientButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Function onPressed;

  RaisedGradientButton({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    this.width = double.infinity,
    this.height = 40.0,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Gradient _gradient = LinearGradient(
        colors: [ColorUtils.themeGradientStart, ColorUtils.themeGradientEnd]);
    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0)),
          gradient: _gradient,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey[500],
              offset: Offset(0.0, 1.5),
              blurRadius: 1.5,
            ),
          ]),
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: InkWell(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0)),
            onTap: onPressed,
            child: Center(
              child: child,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i have a error on your 'CommonStyles' it says undefined

Comment: same error i encounter bro. the "provider", "CommonStyles", "LoginReq"

Comment: @ZionMiguel i have removed "provider" from answer and added missing files in answer

Comment: 'CommonStyles' class not FOUND   
   
    //    decoration: CommonStyles.textFormFieldStyle("Email", ""),

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Login page With Password Username Validation**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'SignUp.dart';
import 'Home.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Login createState() => _Login();
}

final unameController = TextEditingController();
final passController = TextEditingController();  
String uname = "uname";
String pass = "pass";

class _Login extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Smple Login",
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 400,
            width: 300,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("Login Here"),
                TextField(
                  controller: unameController,

                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mobile_friendly,),
                    hintText: "Username",
                  ),
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: passController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.keyboard,),
                    hintText: "PassWord",
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUp()));
                      },
                      child: Text("Create Account?"),
                    )),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text("Submit"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (uname == unameController.text &&
                        pass == passController.text) {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  Home(username: "Hello World from Login")));
                    } else {
                      Fluttertoast.showToast(
                          msg: "Invalid Username or Password");
                          unameController.text="";
                          passController.text="";
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```